# Sort divs by date / time with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script which creates a lot of divs with the a `data-date` attribute and has a time format of `Tue Aug 16 2016 12:27:21 GMT+0100 (BST)`

An example set could be:

```
<div class="socialBox" data-date="Tue Aug 10 2016 12:30:21 GMT+0100 (BST)" data-type="twitter">
<div class="socialBox" data-date="Tue Aug 14 2016 12:10:21 GMT+0100 (BST)" data-type="facebook">
<div class="socialBox" data-date="Tue Aug 13 2016 15:27:21 GMT+0100 (BST)" data-type="youtube">
<div class="socialBox" data-date="Tue Aug 03 2016 18:27:21 GMT+0100 (BST)" data-type="instagram">
```

The divs are appended to a blank div from a variety of different functions and then I run the JS to sort the divs and append it to the original blank div again but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the script

```
loadTwitter(twitter);
loadFacebook(facebook);
loadYoutube(youtube);
loadInstagram(instagram);

// DOESN'T WORK YET (THE BELOW)

var board = $("#social-board");
var boards = board.children('.socialBox');

boards.sort(function(a, b) {
    var an = $(a).data("date").getTime();
    var bn = $(b).data("date").getTime();

    if(an > bn) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(an < bn) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
});

boards.detach().appendTo(board);
```

Could anyone help me out? I'm not sure if its the appending to the `div` element or the JS sort function itself.

Comment: Note: All those comparisons can be turned into `return $(a).data("date") - $(b).data("date");` if `.data("date")` returns a `Date` instance (as it seems to), because A) The `-` operator will coerce the dates to numbers, which is equivalent to calling `getTime`, and B) You don't have to specifically return -1, 1, and 0; any negative or positive number is fine for the first two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. Detaching them up front and then using `.get` to get a real array instead of a jQuery object.
2. Sorting them (which can be a lot simpler)
3. Appending that array back to `#social-board`

so:

```
var boards = board.children('.socialBox').detach().get();
// --------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// A bit shorter :-)
boards.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date($(a).data("date")) - new Date($(b).data("date"));
});

board.append(boards); // <== switched this to append
```

Live example:

```js
// Wait a sec so we can see the old order...
setTimeout(function() {
  // Now sort them

  var board = $("#social-board");
  var boards = board.children('.socialBox').detach().get();

  boards.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(a).data("date")) - new Date($(b).data("date"));
  });

  board.append(boards);
}, 600);
```

```html
<div id="social-board">
  <div class="socialBox" data-date="2016-08-10T11:30:21.000Z" data-type="twitter">2016-08-10T11:30:21.000Z</div>
  <div class="socialBox" data-date="2016-08-03T17:27:21.000Z" data-type="instagram">2016-08-03T17:27:21.000Z</div>
  <div class="socialBox" data-date="2016-08-14T11:10:21.000Z" data-type="facebook">2016-08-14T11:10:21.000Z</div>
  <div class="socialBox" data-date="2016-08-13T14:27:21.000Z" data-type="youtube">2016-08-13T14:27:21.000Z</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Note**: You cannot rely on the JavaScript `Date` object parsing dates in the string format you've used. Note the ISO format I've used in the snippet instead.

---

Side note: Unless you're using the features of [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data), you may want to use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) instead. `data` is **not** just an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It's both more and less than that.

Comment: Thanks mate! I use a function called `relative_time` which governs things like "Posted 21 hrs ago" so I made a compromise and in the sort function I use `return new Date($(b).data("date")).toISOString()` - so I'm doing the conversion on the fly.

Comment: @WebDevDanno: No worries, but I think you've misunderstood about the date strings. There's no need for ISO strings in the `sort` callback. The reason for showing ISO strings above was that you cannot trust `new Date` to parse your `data-date` attribute values (`"Tue Aug 10 2016 12:30:21 GMT+0100 (BST)"` and such). That is **not defined** in the JavaScript specification, and can be locale-specific. So `new Date($(a).data("date"))` may well return a `Date` object with an invalid time value -- both here and in your `relative_time` function, if it also assumes `new Date` will parse those.

Comment: this is not sorting for me by date *descending*:  `var dates = [{"formatted_date":"22/09/2018 @ 04:02pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:02:22.485Z"},{"formatted_date":"22/09/2018 @ 04:12pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:12:04.471Z"},{"formatted_date":"22/09/2018 @ 04:05pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:05:45.818Z"},{"formatted_date":"22/09/2018 @ 04:00pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T06:00:46.954Z"},{"formatted_date":"22/09/2018 @ 03:56pm", "iso_string": "2018-09-22T05:56:13.968Z"}];` WITH: `var sorted_dates = dates.sort(function (a, b) {return b.iso_string - a.iso_string;});`

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is right, but your logic is slightly off in your sort function. This is the code I use to sort dates:

```
var reverse = false; // ascending/descending flag
var board = $("#social-board");
var boards = board.children('.socialBox');
var orderedBoards = boards.slice().sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
  var value1 = new Date($(elem1).data("date")).getTime(),
      value2 = new Date($(elem2).data("date")).getTime();
  if (reverse) {
    // descending
    return -(value1 > value2) || +(value1 < value2) || (isNaN(value1)) - (isNaN(value2));
  }
  // ascending
  return +(value1 > value2) || -(value1 < value2) || (isNaN(value1)) - (isNaN(value2));
});
board.empty().append(orderedBoards);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution:

HTML:

```
<ul class="sort-list">
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="2018-06-30 22:00">3</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="2018-06-29 21:00">2</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="2018-06-27 22:00">1</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="2018-07-01 22:00">4</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="2018-07-02 22:00">5</li>

</ul>

<button onclick="chat_order()">
test
</button>
```

JS:

```
function chat_order() {
    var container = $(".sort-list");
    var items = $(".sort-item");

    items.each(function() {
       // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
       // standardized date format
       var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date");
       /*console.log(BCDate);
       var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];*/
       var standartDate = new Date(BCDate).getTime();
       $(this).attr("data-event-date", standartDate);
                console.log(standartDate);
    });


    items.sort(function(a,b){
        a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
        b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
        return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
    }).each(function(){
        container.prepend(this);
    });

}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2fr0vmhu/294/

Comment: Instead of `attr("data-event-date")` why not use `data("data-event-date")` (I just did, works better - using attr were adding unnecesary value in tag).